# Java 8 Filter Array Using Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a `double[]` and I want to filter out (create a new array without) negative values in one line without adding `for` loops. Is this possible using Java 8 lambda expressions?

In python it would be this using generators:

```
[i for i in x if i > 0]
```

Is it possible to do something similarly concise in Java 8?

Comment: What do you mean by _filter out_? Do you mean create a new array without those values?

Comment: Not sure if possible with a `double[]`, but easy with a `List`: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/java-8-lambda-tutorial/filter-tutorial.php

Comment: FYI that's called a list comprehension. Generators use parens, like this: `(i for i in x if i > 0)`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating a `DoubleStream` from the array, filtering out the negatives, and converting the stream back to an array. Here is an example:

```
double[] d = {8, 7, -6, 5, -4};
d = Arrays.stream(d).filter(x -> x > 0).toArray();
//d => [8, 7, 5]
```

If you want to filter a reference array that is not an `Object[]` you will need to use the [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method which takes an `IntFunction` to get an array of the original type as the result:

```
String[] a = { "s", "", "1", "", "" };
a = Arrays.stream(a).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I think that is about as concise as Java will get :D

Comment: I think it should be double[] toArray = Arrays.stream(d).filter(x -> x > 0).toArray();

Comment: @Raj that's valid also if you want to assign the returned array to a separate reference.

Comment: I think the call to `toArray()` will return an `Object []` instead, so that second line might fail with a cast exception. Thanks!

Comment: @JesúsZazueta I have edited the answer, does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

even simpler, adding up to `String[]`,

use built-in filter `filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)` of `org.apache.commons.lang3`

`import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;`

```
    String test = "a\nb\n\nc\n";
    String[] lines = test.split("\\n", -1);


    String[]  result = Arrays.stream(lines).filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty).toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lines));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

and output:

`[a, b, , c, ]
[a, b, c]`