# cannot resolve Arrays.stream in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use a lambda expression in Android Studio to [filter an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112715/java-8-filter-array-using-lambda)

```
String[] a = { "s", "", "1", "", "" };
a = Arrays.stream(a).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

I am getting an error on compilation 'Cannot resolve method `stream`'

[image]

Other Lambda expressions (say for click events) *are* working and I am targetting java 1.8 in my app gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    incremental = false;
}
```

Under `File -> Project Stucture` I am using the embedded JDK and even when I switch to the latest Java 8 JDK i still get the error.

Interestingly if i switch *back* to VERSION_1_7 then my prevously working lambda statements give a compile error.

How can I get this filter working in Android Studio?

Comment: Could there be an old rt.jar in your compiler configuration?

Comment: @PaulHicks could you indicate where I check the compiler configuration?

Comment: Androids prior to Nougat don't support Java 8.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev why do the lambdas work then?

Comment: [They don't](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev see my updated screenshot above please. the lambda compiles on android studio (and runs on android 5.1.1) but `Arrays.stream` doesnt

Comment: I think this is only an emulation. Maybe IDE change the lamdas to anonymous classes at compile time. Streams are more complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between Java8 language features and Java8-API. Android supports only a subset of each.
Lambdas are a Java8 language feature. Whereas the stream API is an API introduced in the Java8-API.

Language features are implemented by the compiler and might need some API-Support, whereas the Java-API needs to be present on the device.

This means you can use lambdas with apps having minSdkVersion < 24 but you can't use the stream API, since it is only part of the sdk for >=24.

https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#supported-features

You have the same in other "Java-technologies". Typically the Eclipse compiler can have a source compatibility of 1.8 and a target compatibility of 1.7, this would allow you to use lambdas, but not streams (when running on a java7 vm, on a java8 vm it would work)