# What is this syntax in java?

Tags: java, syntax

I find a syntax **String[]::new** in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24112752) answer.
but I search this in google can't find useful information.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a shorthand for a lambda, a recent addition to Java:

```
size -> new String[size]
```

which in turn is shorthand for an IntFunction:

```
new IntFunction<String[]> {
  @Override
  String[] apply(int size) {
    return new String[size];
  }
}
```

As you can see, these additions to Java 8 make the language a bit less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to a constructor. The `ClassName::method` is just a terser syntax for using lambda expressions that call existing methods (in this case `new`), as opposed to those which call anonymous methods.