# How do I pick a group of numbers form an array based on a given range?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int [] numList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int rangeLowerBound = 2
int rangeUpperbound = 8
```

Is there some sort of standard way to grab a group of numbers from the array that fall within the range, then put those numbers into a new Array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112715/java-8-filter-array-using-lambda [Duplicate]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this range is inclusive,

```
int[] inRange = Arrays.stream(numList).filter(x -> x >= rangeLowerBound && x <= rangeUpperbound).toArray();
// inRange = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```