# how can i make multiple loops?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am facing a problem with java array loops well, this is the problem

Use the space below to write main method that reads 5 integer values into an array named list.
Then, use the array to output the positive values followed by the negative values and ignore
zeros.

```
Sample Output
Enter 5 numbers: 10 -3 0 -4 9
List: 
10
9
-3
-4
```

and this is the answer:

```
int [] list = new int[5];
// 1pt
Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);

// 3pts
System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    list[i] = read.nextInt();

// 3 pts
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    if (list[i] > 0)
        System.out.println(list[i]);

// 3 pts
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    if (list[i] < 0)
        System.out.println(list[i]);
```

but i do not know how to make them work together if you get me

Comment: You can sort items of the array before printing them.

Comment: by combining the logic of the last two loops in one. or by just using one single loop. use a StringBuilder to build the output, which you only print after completion of your loop(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet to sort the array and then later display it and put a condition in between which checks whether an element of the array is `0` or not.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++){
        if(i < 5){
            System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                list[i] = read.nextInt();
            continue;
        }
        for(int j = i ; i < 10 ; j++){
            if(list[i] > list[j]){
                int temp = list[i] ;
                list[i] = list[j] ;
                list[j] = temp ;
            }
        }
        if(i == 5){
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                if(list[i] != 0)
                    System.out.println(list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I guess this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do using Java8 can be this

```
    Integer [] list = new Integer[5];
    Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");
    for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++)
     list[i] = read.nextInt();

    List<Integer> newList = Arrays.asList(list).stream().filter(x -> x !=0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(newList,(a,b) -> {
        if(a>b)
            return -1;
        else if(b>a)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    });
    System.out.println(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stream filter() in java to get elements according to your need here we will check that value is not equal to zero `(s-> s != 0)` and here we are using lambdas in java 8.

```
    int [] list = new int[5];
    Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers:");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      list[i] = read.nextInt();
      if(i == 4)
        list = (Arrays.stream(list).filter(s -> s != 0).toArray());
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

[Java Stream filter()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-filter-java-examples/) , [filter array using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112715/java-8-filter-array-using-lambda/24112752)